# I can't disable PHP errors

Tags: php, ubuntu, error-reporting

So what's going on is I tried

```
ini_set('display_errors', 'Off');
error_reporting(0);
```

Right below `<?php`, but this didn't seem to stop displaying them. So I went to the `php.ini` and went to `display_errors` and saw that it was set to `Off`. But it still showed.

So I went and did `phpinfo()` and `display_errors` along with `display_startup_errors` are both off. Also `html_errors` is off. I'm not sure if this will help, but it says `error_reporting` is set to `-10241`. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you running your own code, or some framework code? And is the php.ini listed in `phpinfo()` the same one you examined?

Comment: After modifying the Php.ini did you restart apache?

Comment: No framework. All pure PHP. And yes it is. I just checked the location @MichaelBerkowski

Comment: Yes I did. I used `sudo service apache2 restart` @DarylGill

Comment: Firstly, what code is causing these *said* errors?

Comment: Well they're notices. What I do is if `loggedIn` is true then do this. But otherwise I'm not doing anything. So it doesn't affect the site whatsoever. Plus the code is easily thousands of line ;) @Darren

Comment: @Idris I see, wouldn't want to ready through all of that haha. If I may ask, what kind of notices are they?

Comment: I get `Notice: Undefined index: loggedIn in /var/www/html/profile.php on line 64`, this is because `loggedIn` isn't set. And `Undefined variable: reprint in /var/www/html/profile.php on line 72` because loggedIn still isn't set. I check if they're set, but it would be a _long_ process. So I'm just trying to hide them  @Darren

Comment: @Idris That is a funky issue, just tried on a local stack (PHP 5.5.9) and it works perfectly.

Comment: These can be easily solved with an isset condition. Do not hide your errors. Resolve them.

Comment: It seemed to work perfectly fine on my local machine. But when I moved online I had issues. I'm on Digital Ocean, if that makes a difference. @Darren

Comment: Would you rather go through thousands of line and add an `isset` condition, or disable them with one slight change? @DarylGill

Comment: @Idris i agree with DarylGill on using `isset()` but the scope of this question is to solve your error reporting issues here. Does your host allow you to set the `ini` explicitly like that with `ini_set()`? What version of `PHP` is running and what happens if you try `ini_set('display_errors', 0);`

Comment: I'd personally sit through the thousand lines to resolve any triggered errors. By all means pastebin/Gist the code it's self with dependencies so I can recreate the messages, I will have a debugged code script for you tomorrow (heading to sleep soon)

Comment: I don't mind doing it myself. I really appreciate you taking interest in it. Also I guess doing things the right way, end up being better products @DarylGill

Comment: Same thing happens if I try `ini_set('display_errors', 0);` and `5.5.9` @Darren

Comment: I'd personally choose a package which handled errors over turning reporting off. Imho it's extremely lazy and is not a fix, as turning off errors will stop one seeing more important errors. Or even if one logs errors with no display, error logs would be flooded with unhandled notices and will make said error log a large file very quickly (as every refresh will input duplicate error messages with different time stamps)

Comment: U can route the errors in your own callback see. See ´set_error_handler´

Answer (score 3):

Do not change the value of error reporting to solve the issue. If display_errors is off, errors are not display independently of the error_reporting setting. This way you will not display errors but you can still log them.

The following should work:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 'Off');
```

If it doesn't work it could be that your server configuration does not allow you to change settings from PHP scripts. ini_set() returns FALSE on failure. So first of all you should check what value that call is returning. Make sure that ini_set is not listed among disabled PHP functions (disable_functions in php.ini).

If you are asking yourself why errors are still being displayed even if in php.ini the display_errors is Off, you can check the actual value of display_errors during the script execution:

```
ini_get('display_errors')
```

Pemember that PHP settings could be changed also in Apache host configuration and in .htaccess files. So check if you have an htacces that enables display_errors. Something like this:

```
php_flag display_errors on
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
ini_set('display_errors', false);
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't describe what the errors are, so it's possible that your web server (Apache, nginx, etc) are what's throwing the error and not PHP.

If it is PHP, ensure that you're editing the correct php.ini as identified in your phpinfo.php.  Remember that if you edit the php.ini, you will need to restart your PHP process (for example, on some *nix systems:  service php-fpm restart.  Your exact command may vary.)

If it's off in your php.ini, my guess is that it's being overridden somewhere else -- either later in the script ('grep "ini_set" /path/to/project/*.php' will find it).  Also, the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors) states that if the script has fatal errors, it doesn't apply if there are fatal errors:

> Although display_errors may be set at runtime (with ini_set()), it
>   won't have any effect if the script has fatal errors. This is because
>   the desired runtime action does not get executed.